# Panels stacking order in panel.h for C

Tags: c, stack, panel, ncurses

I'm fooling around with `panel.h` and `ncurses.h` in **C**.

At the moment I'm interested in the ways of changing **panels stacking order**.
I know that when I call `create_panel` I push panel on top of that stack.
I'm also aware of `bottom_panel()` and `top_panel()` functions that can change stacking order by pushing given panel on top or placing on the bottom of stack or `panel_below()` and `panel_above()` for browsing through the stack of panels.

**My quesion is:** what are other built-in functions for messing with panels order?

For example ( actually that's something I'm trying myself right now ) I create array of 7 windows. And then create array of 7 panels accordingly.

Then I want to change active panel(done and working), move active panel around(done), get active panel on top or bottom(done) and  move active panel deeper or closer to the top one level at the time( not done, problematic ).

I appreciate your help and will be grateful for **NOT** posting complete solutions. I can think of few ways of doing it and want to try them myself later. I just want to be sure I won't spend my time reinventing the wheel by keeping order of panels manually or writing overly-complicated functions for reorganising them by calling functions I already know.

Comment: Clarify the difference between _panel_ and _window_.  i.e., I am confused when you say can _move_ the active window around.  I can understand _moving_ a panel, but not a window.

Comment: @ryyker I changed `window` to `panel` in a few places, but since they are almost the same thing I can't be more clear. You either know functions that I'm looking for or you don't. Example, is, well, just an example, and has little to do with my actual problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no other functions for changing the order of panels, `top_panel()` and `bottom_panel()` are the only way.

Calling `top_panel()` and `bottom_panel()` does not redraw the screen so you can call them multiple times to reorder the stack.